# How to obtain adult norms for Raven's progressive matrices?

Tags: test, iq

Raven's Progressive Matrices:

> is a nonverbal group test typically used in educational settings. It is usually a 60-item test used in measuring abstract reasoning and regarded as a non-verbal estimate of fluid intelligence. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven%27s_Progressive_Matrices)

Where can one find adult norms for [Raven's progressive matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven%27s_Progressive_Matrices)?

For instance, how can I find the percentile for a raw score of 56 out of 60 for a 36 year old caucasian male?

Comment: Hi, welcome at CogSci. Could you perhaps explain a bit more about tool you are using? How does it work and where do you use it for? Also a reference to the tool would be much appreciated. The more context you provide, the better people will be able to give an answer :)

Comment: I added a little comment. Raven's is arguably the most common measure of g when only a single test is used.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to obtain a copy of the test manual. It includes norm tables for different groups.

If you Google it you might be able to find out [where to purchase a copy](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=raven+manual+standard+progressive+matrices&oq=raven+manual+standard+progressive+matrices&gs_l=serp.3..35i39k1j0i22i30k1l3.2212.2212.0.2970.1.1.0.0.0.0.208.208.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.1.208.O-lWxkEDWQ0)

Equally, many psychology departments have test libraries and they are likely to have a copy.

It's also possible that some journal articles that have used Raven's could provide a rougher approximation to actual test norms.